how do I read and write from/to a JSON file in the root folder of my project?
I'm trying to access a JSON file in the same folder as my App.js file with expo-file-system to read and write from and to it, but I can't seem to be able to no matter what I do.
Here's an image of my project's folder (yes weird file names but that's not important right now)
Expo version 51.0.38
I tried using FileSystem.bundleDirectory with my file name:
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system"

...
...
...

const JSONPath = FileSystem.bundleDirectory + "myData.json";

console.log(JSONPath); // outputs  asset:/myData.json
        
FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(JSONPath).then(res => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res)); // Doesn't write anything to the console
});

but this throws an exception:

Console Warning: Possible unhandled promise rejection (id: 2): Error: Call to function 'ExponentFileSystem.readAsStringAsync' has been rejected. -> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: myData.json

I also tried the same but with FileSystem.documentDirectory:
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system"

...
...
...

const JSONPath = FileSystem.documentDirectory + "myData.json";

console.log(JSONPath); // outputs  file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/myData.json

FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(JSONPath).then(res => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res));  // Doesn't write anything to the console
});

but this throws another exception:

Console Warning: Possible unhandled promise rejection (id: 3): Error: Call to function 'ExponentFileSystem.readAsStringAsync' has been rejected. -> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/myData.json (No such file or directory)

I also tried using @expo/json-file, but it threw an error saying that it uses fs, which is incompatible with Expo.
So I'm stuck here, I've been searching for the whole day and I found nothing, so any help would be very much appreciated.
Also, while I'm at it, what's the difference between documentDirectory and bundleDirectory ??

try to check if file exists before trying to read it. if it dose not then create it using the expo lib as it also adds the the right permissions

I created the file myself so it exists, but I don't know how I can get to it
